# MapView Issues / Empty Tiles

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, api-key

I'm having issues with a MapView.. I've used MapView's before so I really don't know what the problem is, it's probably something simple that I'm overlooking but it's driving me insane. The app installs and runs fun, but the MapView tiles do no load. All I see is an empty grid. I know the API key (debug keystore) is fun because I have another project using it that works perfectly. I've included my manifest, layout, and activity files to help diagnose the problem. I'd appreciate any help - I'm baffled!

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.***.studybuddy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".StudyBuddy"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapInterface" >
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".FriendService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.***.studybuddy.FriendService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideMenuInterface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapInterface"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/sideMenuInterface"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/sideMenuInterface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick" >
        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="0f6nuBOcz_OlhAQm3B3Xljy5hDOVrR1FO3KM***"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity:

```
package com.***.studybuddy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MapInterface extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener {
    static int USER_ID = 1;
    static MapView mapView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapinterface);

        configure();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private void configure() {
        findViews();
        startService(new Intent(FriendService.class.getName()));
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
    }

    private void findViews() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.topMenu:
            ((View)view.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Empty Tiles]

Answer (score 0):

I once had the problem that I missed some permissions. I need this 3 permissions (you are missing the first two of them.):

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION”></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION”></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.INTERNET”></uses-permission>
```

Comment: added the permissions, no change... the maptiles are still empty.

Comment: then the only thing I can imagine is that something with signing your app went wrong. You did as described here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html ?

Comment: yup.. i'm gonna try generating a new debug keystore.. i'll let you know if that works

Comment: that did the trick, i just registered for a new apiKey with the new debug keystore